# Regex Caller ID (match suffix)

Tags: contacts, tasker, automation, caller-id

I get calls from a queue from my phone provider. The phone provider distinguishes these calls by adding a suffix.

```
12345678
```

becomes

```
1234567801
```

I would like to make a contact with a phone number which matches all numbers matching the suffixed numbers in order to have an at a glance recognition of queue calls, as opposed to direct calls.

Is there any way to achieve this? Can it be done with tasker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any app that would allow creating a contact with wildcard or regex but you can consider Tasker to execute a particular action as a recognition of those particular numbers.

- Profile: State → Phone → Call

  - Type: Incoming
  - Number: `*01`

    `*` is the wildcard here which would  match anything. `01` is the suffix you want at the end of the number.

How you want to recognize those numbers is up to you. Under a task you can show a:

- Toast: Alert → Flash
- Notification: Alert → Notify
- Popup: Alert → Popup
- May be, a Scene like this:

  <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

  [image: IMG:]

Comment: You can also block the calls if you want to. There is also a dedicated app I know which can block calls based on numbers using certain regex. See my answer here: [Customize call blocking](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110479)

Comment: While it includes the solution, wouldn't it also show non-provider calls ending with 01 as provider calls?  Where I live, the first 4digits of number are specific to provider, I'm not sure if that is standard everywhere.

Comment: Not really my concern if you ask me. OP asked us something to take care of which I perfectly did and I also knew this point would be raised by somebody too. If OP raises your point then I would ask them to provide a definite use-case in the question itself so that I can update my answer accordingly (subjected to my discretion).

Answer (score 0):

You may create a single contact with multiple numbers. Just copy >> paste the original number into a new number field and add the suffix. I don't think there is a limit to the number of `phone number` fields.

Comment: IMO, the question is about expecting any number ending with a particular suffix to be get recognized by OP when the call from that number comes and OP prefers to have a contact amassing all those number under a hood. I understand, as per your answer, a person has to already know all the numbers ending with that suffix but how can we expect anyone to supposedly know all those numbers already. Could it be that I've misunderstood something here?

Comment: Op should have misused the word suffix instead of prefix. General phone provider calls will have static prefix. I think the OP meant numbers like 12345678, 1234567801, 1234567802... Blocking *01 will have a much wider range of numbers, even numbers out of a single network operator . If what I assume is true, OP might need to create single contact with 100 numbers only changing in suffix.

Comment: @BharatG Firelord is correct.

Comment: @Magnus Rose in such case my answer is invalid. Could you post 3 or 4 such numbers, im just curious. :)

Comment: 1234567801
2345678901
3456789101
4567891201
The first 8 digits are unknown. Could be any valid phone number.

Comment: Are the first 8digits always ordered numbers (digits n, n+1, n+2, n+3...) ? Or could they be randomized as well?